# Append a Value to a Fixed Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to duplicate an array, but make it one more space longer than the original one. In the new space created, I want to set that to the variable "val". I get an error when I try to compile this code, but I do not understand why. The original array has a guaranteed length of 3.

```
   double[] array2 = new double[4];

   array2[3] = val;

   return array2[3];
```

Comment: what is error message ? is it null pointer exception or what

Comment: it says "loss of precision required : double[] found: double

Comment: What is val??  Show complete valid code.

Comment: `val` is a `float`? There is really no way to know what the error is when you have provided -20% of your code. Come on.

Comment: All we can guess based on what you posted is that the method is supposed to return an array of doubles (hence the message `required : double[]`), but you're returning a single double: array2[3] (hence the message `found: double`). But it would be much easier if you posted all the relevant code in your question, as well as the exact and complete error message.

Comment: is val is of valid double type.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29) here since that would take care of copying over the elements in the old array.

```
public static double[] addToEnd(double[] array1, double val) {
    // copy over elements; you don't even need to think 
    // about whether the array has 3 elements or a 100 elements
    int[] array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length + 1);

    // val is copied to the last index
    array2[array2.length - 1] = val;

    return array2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try in such a way

```
private double method() {
    double[] array2 = new double[4];
    double val = 10.0;
    array2[3] = val;
    return array2[3];
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of such a method. All it does is, basically, `return 10.0;`.

Comment: val is staticaly set for a moment as user did't shown val type inside his code.Actually it is not 10.0 ,instead of this it could be anything valid double type.

Comment: the `val` should have been passed to the function instead of blatant hard-coding inside the function

Comment: Even if it was passed as argument, the method would still be equivalent to `return arg;`. Still pointless.

Comment: the method is supposed to return a `double[]`, not a double; that is quite clear from `loss of precision required : double[] found: double`

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, i think you are referring to what I noted in the second comment?